# Multiple select in input

Tags: php, html, input, foreach, warnings

I cant find the error. I saw multiple examples and they have it in the same way. But is giving me the next error:

> **Warning:** Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in whatever **on line 180**

This is the html:

```
<select class="form-control" id="selected-seats" name="selected-seats[]" multiple="">
    <option value="cart-item-4_9">R4 S9</option>
    <option value="cart-item-4_10">R4 S10</option>
</select>
```

This is the php:

```
 $seat = (isset($_POST['selected-seats']) ? $_POST['selected-seats']:'');
                        //if (is_array($seat)) {                    
                            foreach ($seat as $selectedOption)
                                echo "Seats ".$selectedOption."\n";
                        //}
```

Comment: It means that whatever you supplied in `$seat` is not an array. You commented out the code that checks if it actually is an array, too.

Comment: Yeah but it not making the echo if I uncomment the line

Comment: You could put an `else`-cause to the `if (is_array())` statement, to process in the event it could be a string instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep your data consistent. You're expecting an array, but giving it an empty string.

Use this as your ternary instead:

```
$seat = (isset($_POST['selected-seats']) ? $_POST['selected-seats']:array());
```

Comment: I put your code and now the warning is gone, but why do u think the echo is not showing?

Comment: it's not working because `$_POST['selected-seats']` is not being set. Above that line paste this one: `echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST); exit;`   ... that will show you what is actually getting posted to the script.

Comment: @AdriánVázquez - I just looked at your code again. It's not working because you're using multiple which sends an array, AND you've got `[]` on the end of your name, which is also sending an array, so you've got an array of arrays. Remove the `[]` and it should work as you expected.

Comment: Sorry but he echo is not working but the warning is gone without [] too

Comment: @AdriánVázquez - That's all I can tell you with the info you've provided. If you want to post the full code I'll be happy to take a look.

Comment: The code is too large because it has javascript too I will try again and see if I found something else. But thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Should it not be:

```
 $seat = (isset($_POST['selected-seats']) ? $_POST['selected-seats']: **array()**);
```

I'm assuming it's hitting the false condition and a string is invalid for the loop.